# Encode a sqlalchemy text query

Tags: python, encoding, sqlalchemy

I am trying to execute this statement without success because I get:

> "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xc9' in position 276: ordinal not in range(128)"

My code is:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

engine = sa.create_engine("my connection (cannot show it)")
conn = engine.connect()
q = text("SELECT * FROM STORES WHERE CADENA = 'ÉLIAS'")

result = conn.execute(q).fetchall()
print(result)
```

As you see, the conditional of the SQL query has a "É" which cannot be encoded.

What can I do to solve this?  If I write `.encode('utf-8')` at the end of the text, it says

> AttributeError: 'TextClause' object has no attribute 'encode'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what database are you using with SQLAlchemy ?

Comment: Exadata from Oracle, sorry I did not mention it

Comment: no prob, i cannot reproduce it, that's why i ask

Comment: can you try with `text(u"SELECT * FROM STORES WHERE CADENA = 'ÉLIAS'")`  or `text("SELECT * FROM STORES WHERE CADENA = 'ÉLIAS'".encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: Your connection settings barring username, password, host etc. are important information. Fake/redact the sensitive parts, but do include the rest.

Comment: @PRMoureu it doesn´t work! Still getting same message

Comment: This worked for me: text(u"SELECT * FROM STORES WHERE CADENA LIKE '%LIAS'")

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @IljaEverilä Python 3